# Area 51 in help center is not written according to trademark guidance

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, help-center, wording

Stack Exchange sites do all have the following page in the help center:
***Help Center* → *Asking* → *What topics can I ask about here?***

The last paragraph contains the following sentence (emphasis mine):

> [...] If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at **Area51**, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Note that this paragraph is not present in the page on Meta Stack Exchange, but for example on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), ...

In the *Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks* which can be found [here](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), it is mentioned that Area 51 is written in **two words** (emphasis as in source):

> **Area 51** (two words) is the site used to propose new Stack Exchange sites for the Stack Exchange Network.

Given the referenced guidelines, I think the help pages in question across the whole Stack Exchange Network should be updated to use the correct form of *Area 51* (two words).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no global source for that text - the article is overridden on each and every site you have mentioned, so to fix it, one has to go through all sites, looking for the text and fixing it there.

I have done so for the places you have linked to and mentioned in your question.

If anyone finds additional sites that are incorrect, comment here with a link to the help page article. I will fix those.

---

Update:

I've run a query across all help center articles for `>Area51<` and corrected ~120 articles.

Comment: [Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Hinduism](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic), [Chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),  [Sci-fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)etc.

Comment: Almost every site has `Area51` written :0

Comment: @Oded I think it's on all the sites of the network. Even *Documentation Beta* has this paragraph (right now, the beta seems not to be accessible). It would probably be necessary to check and change it for *all the sites* individually, including all of the new proposals in Area 51 that already have a site (in beta). Of course, the template should be adjusted as well in order to have it clean from the beginning when a new site is created in the future.

Comment: Thing is, @Matt - the template **doesn't have the link**. As you have posted, Meta SE (where the templates live) doesn't have it. So, one has to go through each and every site where the template has been overridden in order to update it.

Comment: @Oded I totally understand that this must be done individually, as I mentioned in my previous comment. To the other point: With *template* I meant the text which got inserted while overriding it for a specific site. Since it is the same wording in all of them, I suppose there must be a *source* where it is drawn from when a new site is created. Have a look at http://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic or http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ... Both of these sites are in beta and have the exact same text (except the site name). That **template** I am talking about.